# Blocking issue in Express / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I got some blocking issue with express in node.js.
Currently, I have this code now:

```
router.get('/Hello', function(req, res, next) {
  (async ()=>{
      try{
          await api.connect();
          let result=await api.HandleSomethins();
          await api.disconnect();
      }catch(err){
       console.log(err);
      }
  })();
  return res.status(json(result));
});
```

There is no problem with above code, and I just use async/await to synchronize something heavy loading process.

Then I got a situation below:

- 1.UserA use this url to connect my node.js, and UserA is waitting for 
    responding now.
- 2.UserB also connect in this time, so node.js can't handle UserB's request immediately.
- (note).I need send response to User client(iOS/Android).

Maybe node server will got UserC,D,etc... in the same time. What should I do can handle this situation? child_proess? cluster? or something else?

Comment: It depends on what `api.HandleSomethins()` does. Is it CPU-heavy? Also, is it really necessary to connect/disconnect from the "api" for each request?

Comment: Off-topic. I'm almost sure there is a problem with the above code. It should throw reference error on `result` being not defined.

Comment: Please show the `api.connect()`  and `api.HandleSomethins()` code.

Comment: I am not sure it CPU-heavy, but it need time to do something

Comment: I simplify detail code ,and just use HandleSomething() to represent 
complicated api here. In fact, the api don't feedback something to me, and result just according to the respond of api( result may be a custom flag)

Comment: If you want see api in detail, see this below:
https://github.com/rippex/ripple-node-examples/blob/master/makePayment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something just like this:

```
router.get('/Hello', async (req, res, next) => {
        let result = null;
        try {
              await api.connect();
              result = await api.HandleSomethins();
              await api.disconnect();
        } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
        }

        return res.status(json(result));
});
```

Comment: Mark as answered. Thank you.